# Windows 10 script to enable/disable TCP port

Tags: powershell, testing, cmd, windows-10, firewall

I want to simulate Oracle disconnect for my app. I need to enable/disable outgoing traffic to port 1521 quickly.

I think the best way is to add/remove a rule into the Windows Firewall.

Is there a CMD or PowerShell scrip I can use? Or WMI in C#?

*(Note: I cannot disable networking as a whole because there are different connections are used in my code and only 1521 needs to be disabled).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for Anas Atef, I had to roll the sleeves up. Here is what one needs in the situation like mine:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Disabling Port 1521" -Action Block -Direction Outbound -Profile Any -Protocol tcp -RemotePort 1521
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Disabling Port 1521" -Action Allow
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Disabling Port 1521" -Action Block
Remove-NetFirewallRule -Name "{751a86cb-2ef3-4eba-8c95-68aa7e4bde18}"
```

**New** creates the rule. The display name is whatever you like.

**Set** then helps you to enable/disable the rule effectively.

Then use **Remove** once you are done testing. The Name in the Remove command is the guid which you get after running New (watch the output).

Answer (score 1):

Try This , This command will block Any outbound traffic from port 1521 for any app or tool :

> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Disabling Port 1521" -Action Block
>   -Direction Outbound -DynamicTarget Any -EdgeTraversalPolicy Block -Profile Any -Protocol tcp -RemotePort 1521

Comment: This Is a powershell command, of course you can do this using CMD with the "  netsh advfirewall firewall" . Hope This Helps

Comment: Thank you.. will try tomorrow.. but are you sure we are talking the same things? `Any outbound traffic from port 1521 `.. I need to disable all local outbound traffic to **remote** port 1521

Comment: The Traffic Exits through port 1521 right ? if there is any traffic trying to go out using port 1521 it should be blocked

Comment: New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Disabling Port 1521" -Action Block -Direction Outbound -DynamicTarget Any -EdgeTraversalPolicy Block -LocalPort 1521 -Profile Any -Protocol 1521 -RemotePort 1521

Comment: Here try it again notice the last part of the command "-RemotePort 1521" just added it. I think it should be fine now

Comment: Yes that should do it.. remove  -LocalPort 1521 - its wrong. local port is nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: Ya I misunderstood your question,. Tell me if it worked

Comment: no it doesn't work.. it creates the rule.. if you run it again it creates another one... what I need is **two scripts** - enable the rule and then disable it..

Comment: sorry. I felt like I am working for you full-time... so I decided to quit.. send the reminder of my salary to a charity of your choice.... oh.. there was no salary??.. um... how embarrassing...

Comment: NO need for payment , you can decide whatever you want to do . sorry for the late response , I am a bit busy just give me some time ill make the second script

Comment: Oh sorry for not noticing your replies,  good thing you solved the rest, try to save the commands in a txt file or a ps1 file. I was not very helpful here , however i hope I can be of better use next time